# Facebook not sending get parameter after login success

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using php sdk for my facebook application.
I am using following code for login url

```
if (isset($username)) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope' => $scope,
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.mysite.com/redirect.php?username=' . $username
            )
```

My problem is that after login when facebook redirects page to redirect.php but it removes `?username=ursername`. 
I need the username as get parameter after login.
How can i do this. Please suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying? Please elaborate more

Comment: I am trying to redirect user in this page after facebook login 
http://www.mysite.com/redirect.php?username=krishna
but facebook redirects to http://www.mysite.com/redirect.php

Comment: What error it is showing?

Comment: its not showing any error. its just redirecting me to redirect.php i need to redirect on redirect.php?username=myusername

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass username to the redirect_uri. It's not really meant for this, but there is a `state` parameter you can pass that gets returned to you.

See the documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

```
define('REDIRECT_URI',"YOUR-REDIRECT-URL-HERE");
    $user = null;

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
        'cookie' => true
    ));

    if (isset($username)) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope' => $scope,
                'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI
            )
```